# SQL Query variable vs hardcoded value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I need explanation of something, as I couldn't find in on my own (probably because I don't know how to search for it).

I have a SQL Server query with some Common Table Expressions in it, one of those CTEs is selecting data based on date and user being not null e.g.

```
WHERE 
    "dummy"."UsageEnd" >= '20161001' 
    AND "dummy"."UsageEnd" < '20161101' 
    AND "Users"."Login" IS NOT NULL
```

In that form this query executes in ~2 seconds, but I need to change dates to a parameter, as this query will be executed very commonly. But if i change it to:

```
WHERE  
    "dummy"."UsageEnd" >= @start 
    AND "dummy"."UsageEnd" < @end 
    AND "Users"."Login" IS NOT NULL
```

Where `@start` and `@end` are declared as either `datetime` or `varchar`:

```
declare @datestart datetime
set @datestart = '20161001';

declare @dateend datetime
set @dateend = '20161101';
```

This subquery executes in 23-24 seconds, and whole query (as reminder this subquery is in CTE) is taking 7-8 minutes, when previously it was taking 12-15 seconds.

Can someone explain it to me why comparing dates to variables increased execution time so dramatically? Also is it possible, that whole query is taking so long because when in CTE is a variable it will re-evaluate it every time instead of just one?

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans?

Comment: Probably has to do with Parameter sniffing. If you search for it you'll find better descriptions and solutions than I'm able to give. You could try `WITH RECOMPILE` hint, though.

Comment: When you provide a **fixed value** as a date literal, SQL Server can optimize the query for **this exact date value**. If you provide a **parameter**, SQL Server must come up with an execution plan that is as optimal as possible **for ANY possible date value** that you might provide as a parameter value - therefore, it most likely will be a different execution plan

Comment: @marc_s I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: no important thing is what is datatype of UsageEnd and show few date sample.second thing is datatype of paramter will be same.Suppose your parameter name is [@start] then declare local varible called [@start1]=[@start].similarly with [@end].put @start1 and [@end1] in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may well be caused by a combination of everyone's comments:

If your UsageEnd column is not a datetime datatype, but a varchar, the optimizer will first need to convert all values to a datetime type in order to make the comparison with the variables.

The first query with the "hardcoded constants" is already in varchar, so the optimizer is able to perform the comparison much faster.

Both plans will look different and give a clear indication of where to find the problem.

Comment: UsageEnd column is a datetime type, that's why it was strange to me, that comparing it to "hardcoded" varchar was so much quicker. Regarding execution plans unfortunately I'm unable to compare them, as currently I have only read access to that DB (SHOWPLAN permission denied). Knowing my company no one will grant me higher level of access, so I will be unable to analyse this. However solution proposed by HoneyBadger (OPTION(RECOMPILE)) worked like a charm. :)

Comment: Good to know you have found a solution!

Comment: Also, in my own experience, sometimes the query optimizer needs a bit of help when using CTE's, too much or complicated ones may generate a sub-optimal query plan. Converting some of them into temporary tables (@ or #) and then using those tables in the following CTE's, has given me some impressive speed gains as well.

Comment: Thank you for this hint, I will definitely look into it, as this whole query is... "not the best" in terms of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)